# HCSR04 Sonic Sensor Reporting Only 0 CM Troubleshooting

Tags: sensor

```
Edit with Answer:  I had forgot to switchback to using BCM pin numbering from DPI.

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin18_gpio24  

Thanks for the helpful comments.
```

My Sonic Sensor is reporting only zero cm and I don't know how to troubleshoot it.   It was working for a time, but something's gone wrong and I can't find what.

I have a spare sensor and have swamped them out with the same result so I don't think that's it.  I didn't change any wiring on the breadboard between the success and failure so I don't think that's it.

My code is below and I've attached a screen shot of the results of the last test of it running with my hand moving in front of the sensor.

What should I test next?

```
# https://github.com/MarkAHeywood/Bluetin_Python_Echo
from Bluetin_Echo import Echo  # HCSR04 Module
from time import sleep


DistSense = Echo(19, 20)

def report_dist():
samples = 4
try:
    while True:
        d = DistSense.read('cm', samples)
        print(d, 'cm')
        sleep(.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


report_dist()

DistSense.stop()

print('End Of File.')
```

[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: Perhaps try different software? Here is one of my pigpio examples http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_sonar_trigger_echo_py

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I also tried it with the CircuitPython module and got the same result.  https://circuitpython-hcsr04.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: We need a picture of the wiring and voltage divider circuit please.  You can edit the question to add them in.

Comment: Thanks ya'll.  It was a mixup between using BCM and DPI pin numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use BCM Pin numbering instead of DPI.

It was the switching between HC-SR04 modules that tripped me up.  The Adafruit Circuit Pi modules were using DPI and the Bluetin Echo modules was using BCM.

Thanks for the help and comments!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.